# MySql adding too many records for one simple checkbox form?

Tags: mysql, sql, checkbox, many-to-many

I have created a form which contains a lot of checkboxes and i'm wondering how to put this in my MySql database.

here is an example of the form:

---

Label: Amount

Checkboxes: Little | Many | Not so many | etc. etc.

---

Label: Basket Type

Checkboxes: Wooden Basket | Steel Basket | etc. | etc.

---

label: Fruits

Checkboxes: Bananas | Apples | oranges | etc. | etc.

---

In the above example you can pick multiple amounts for example I want a basket with only Little or many pieces fruit in them. You can only choose one basket type, and you can choose one or multiple types of fruits.

All these seperate items have are loaded from the database and an id is added to the checkbox.

The way im storing them now when submitting the form now is:
Table: FruitBasket
Record 1:
Fruitbasket Id = 1
Fruit Id = 1
Basket Type = 1
Amount Id = 1
Record 2:
Fruitbasket Id = 1
Fruit Id = 1
Basket Type = 1
Amount Id = 3

So submitting this form once with lets say 10 checkboxes selected will generate a lot of records. A lot of users will be creating these and there is an option to compare these FruitBaskets.

So my question is, is my current way of storing the data correct because its seems really inefficient and generates so many records. Is there another way of storing all this data as one fruit basket?

Comment: It sounds like you have normalized your tables which would be the best approach for an OLTP system.  This would be the best approach for querying your data.  In your question, the second Fruit basket should have a Fruitbasket Id = 2, right?

Comment: "the second Fruit basket should have a Fruitbasket Id = 2, right?" - yes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a bit-field to store each fruit basket.  You could directly compare fruit baskets using bitwise operators, etc.  If you use Javascript to constrain the users to the options that are really available, then it should work fine.

Example:

```
// Quantities
LITTLE = 1        (0x0000000000000001)
MANY = 2          (0x0000000000000010)
NOT_SO_MANY = 4   (0x0000000000000100)
ALL_QTYS = 7      (0x0000000000000111)

// Basket type
WOODEN = 8        (0x0000000000001000)
STEEL = 16        (0x0000000000010000)
ALL_BASKETS = 24  (0x0000000000011000)

// Fruit types
BANANAS = 32      (0x0000000000100000)
APPLES = 64       (0x0000000001000000)
ALL_FRUIT = 96    (0x0000000001100000)


user_selection = LITTLE | STEEL | BANANAS | APPLES;  (0x0000000001110001)

other_user_selection = LITTLE | WOODEN | BANANAS | APPLES;  (0x0000000001101001)

// use the bitwise AND to compare only the fruit types...
if((user_selection & ALL_FRUIT) == (other_user_selection & ALL_FRUIT))
   echo "Fruit selection is the same!";
```